Error converting nvarchar to datetime in Springboot application
I am trying to execute a stored procedure in SQL Server using spring boot. The get API works fine but the POST Method to pass JSON as parameters is giving error. I am passing id, state_id, and name(city name) as JSON and the error I am getting is:

Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults [Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.] [HikariProxyCallableStatement@1634149277 wrapping sp_executesql SQL: EXEC saveCity  @P0 , @P1 , @P2 , @P3  OUT, @P4  OUT]

On running the SQL Server Profiler, I get the following output:
declare @p6 nvarchar(max) set @p6=NULL declare @p7 nvarchar(max) set @p7=NULL exec sp_executesql N'EXEC saveCity  @P0 , @P1 , @P2 , @P3  OUT, @P4  OUT',N'@P0 int,@P1 int,@P2 nvarchar(4000),@P3 nvarchar(4000) OUTPUT,@P4 nvarchar(4000) OUTPUT',0,2,N'Surat',@p6 output,@p7 output select @p6, @p7

Now if I run the same thing is SQL server independently, it works just fine. I have designed the stored procedure in such a way that creation_timestamp is generated automatically using GETDATE() in SQL Server.
USE [project_1]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int,
        @message varchar(max)

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[saveCity]
        @id = 0,
        @state_id = 2,
        @name = N'SQLCITY',
        @message = @message OUTPUT

SELECT  @message as N'@message' --return string 'TRUE' or 'Error'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

Here is the definition of my stored procedure:
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[saveCity]
    --Defining fields each column in table
        @id int,
        @created_by_id int = 1,
        @creation_timestamp datetime=null,
        @state_id int,
        @name varchar(50),
        @deleted bit=0,
        @deleted_timestamp datetime=null,
        @deleted_by_id int=null,
        @status bit=1,
        @message varchar(max) output
    AS
    BEGIN
        IF @creation_timestamp IS NULL
            SET @creation_timestamp = GETDATE();
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN
                IF (@id=0)
                    BEGIN
                        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM city where name=@name AND state_id=@state_id)
                            BEGIN
                                INSERT INTO city VALUES(@creation_timestamp, @created_by_id, @state_id, @name, @deleted, @deleted_timestamp, @deleted_by_id, @status)
    
                                SET @message='TRUE'
                            END
                        ELSE
                            BEGIN
                                SET @message='City already exists'
                            END
                    END
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM city WHERE id=@id)
                        BEGIN
                            UPDATE city SET state_id=@state_id, name=@name, status=@status WHERE id=@id
                            
                            SET @message='TRUE'
                        END
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            SET @message='City not found'
                        END
                    END
            END
        END TRY
            
        BEGIN CATCH
            BEGIN
                set @message = ERROR_MESSAGE()
            END
        END CATCH
    END

Below is my SpringBoot code:

City.java (model for the table):


@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "saveCity", procedureName = "saveCity", parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "id", mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Integer.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "state_id", mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Integer.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "name", mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "message", mode = ParameterMode.OUT, type = String.class)
})

public class City {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private Timestamp creation_timestamp;

    @Column
    private int created_by_id;

    @Column
    private int state_id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private boolean deleted;

    @Column
    private Timestamp deleted_timestamp;

    @Column
    private Integer deleted_by_id;

    @Column
    private String status;
}



My Controller file: CityController.java:

    @PostMapping("/city")
    public ResponseEntity<String> createCity(@RequestBody City city) {
        try {
            StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("saveCity");
            query.setParameter("id", city.getId());
            query.setParameter("state_id", city.getState_id());
            query.setParameter("name", city.getName());

            // Register the output parameter
            query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("message", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);

            // Execute the stored procedure
            query.getResultList();

            // Get the output parameter value
            String message = (String) query.getOutputParameterValue("message");

            return new ResponseEntity<>(message, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (PersistenceException e) {
            // Handle JPA provider-specific exceptions
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle other exceptions
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }


And even I didn't understand the error as I am not passing any data which needs to be converted to datetime format (as its not needed from the SQL Server snippet). The expected result is that data is stored in the table using stored procedure and API returns some sort of response to it.
Solution:
It worked fine when I commented out this line of code in the Controller:
    // Register the output parameter
                query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("message", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);


This INSERT INTO city VALUES is bad practice, you should always list the columns your are inserting into.

I changed the insert query in the SP with the columns defined. And On running the SQL Server Profiler, I get the following output: declare @p6 nvarchar(max) set @p6=NULL declare @p7 nvarchar(max) set @p7=NULL exec sp_executesql N'EXEC saveCity  @P0 , @P1 , @P2 , @P3  OUT, @P4  OUT',N'@P0 int,@P1 int,@P2 nvarchar(4000),@P3 nvarchar(4000) OUTPUT,@P4 nvarchar(4000) OUTPUT',0,2,N'Surat',@p6 output,@p7 output select @p6, @p7

And there you go, you can see your problem :) so just fix how you call your proc to either name the parameters (like you've done in SSMS) or list them all...

I did the necessary changes in the post, please let me know if there is anything else that is to be updated as well. Thank you!

Add your solution as an answer once you have teated it .

i'm not expert but createNamedStoredProcedureQuery might be wrong, since that's for annotation stuff, what happens if you do: createStoredProcedureQuery

The issue still persists. Here is the SQL Server Profile log: declare @p6 nvarchar(max) set @p6=NULL declare @p7 nvarchar(max) set @p7=NULL exec sp_executesql N'EXEC saveCity  @P0 , @P1 , @P2 , @P3  OUT, @P4  OUT',N'@P0 int,@P1 int,@P2 nvarchar(4000),@P3 nvarchar(4000) OUTPUT,@P4 nvarchar(4000) OUTPUT',0,2,N'Surat',@p6 output,@p7 output select @p6, @p7

Here is the postman response: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults [The formal parameter "@created_by_id" was not declared as an OUTPUT parameter, but the actual parameter passed in requested output.] [HikariProxyCallableStatement@1864116243 wrapping sp_executesql SQL: EXEC saveCity  @P0 , @P1 , @P2 , @P3  OUT, @P4  OUT]

I thought you were going try try specifying all the parameters?

I did but it was giving the following error: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults [Procedure or function saveCity has too many arguments specified.] [HikariProxyCallableStatement@835091320 wrapping sp_executesql SQL: EXEC saveCity  @P0 , @P1 , @P2 , @P3 , @P4 , @P5 , @P6 , @P7 , @P8 , @P9  OUT, @P10  OUT]

@siggemannen I tried using that but it considers the parameters passed as null.

Guess you need to carefully read your framework documentation on how to execute a stored procedure
